# CakePHP retrieving when related model NULL

Tags: orm, cakephp-3.0

I have a null-able relation model, and I am using this standard code to retrieve my records:

```
$this->paginate = [
    'contain' => ['Clients']
];
$coupons = $this->paginate($this->Coupons);
```

I am getting just the records that have client associated.
what is the best practice to make the contain work like `OR`, and not `AND`

EDIT: the relationship is seted as the following:

```
$this->belongsTo('Clients', [
    'foreignKey' => 'client_id',
    'joinType' => 'INNER'
]);
```

Comment: what is the relationship between your model and client? How did you set it?

Comment: Hi @arilia, I edited my question

Comment: I resolved it, thanks I just set the joinType to LEFT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved it by setting the `joinType` to `LEFT`:

```
$this->belongsTo('Clients', [
    'foreignKey' => 'client_id',
    'joinType' => 'LEFT'
]);
```